# database not visible on the db2 server

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

On my db2 server, while I am trying to list the databases on the default path by executing:

```
db2 list database directory
```

this is giving me only one result:

```
System Database Directory

 Number of entries in the directory = 1

Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = REPORTDB
 Database name                        = REPORTDB
 Node name                            = RPTSRV
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Remote
 Authentication                       = SERVER
 Catalog database partition number    = -1
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

however when i am executing the same list command by explicitly mentioning the default path of the database then it is showing me the database infromation:

```
db2 list db directory on /db2/E2Q/
 Local Database Directory on /db2/E2Q

 Number of entries in the directory = 1

Database 1 entry:

 Database alias                       = E2P
 Database name                        = E2P
 Database directory                   = SQL00001
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              = SAP database Q01
 Directory entry type                 = Home
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Database partition number            = 0
```

when i am executing the command  `which db2` i am getting the following result: `/db2/db2e2q/sqllib/bin/db2`

could someone suggest me how to get this fixed? We are unable to catalog the database on the server as well, probably because of this path issue.

Please help.

Comment: What happens when you issue the command `db2 catalog database E2P on /db2/E2Q` ?

Comment: we are not trying to execute that....we dont want the database E2P to be catalogued. Also should db2 list db directory show the information of E2P anyways? what could be wrong here?

Comment: Please clarify what it is you're trying to do.  If you don't want the database E2P cataloged, what is the issue?  `db2 list db directory` does not include it, so .... ?